# Throw a temporary argument passed by reference

Tags: c++, exception

```
inline void my_assert( bool cond, const std::exception &e = my_assert_failed() ) 
{ 
    if ( !cond ) 
      throw e;
}
```

The standard ensures that:

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full expression containing the call.

And for a thrown temporary object:

> The temporary persists as long as there is a handler being executed for that exception.

Can I infer that a temporary that is passed to `my_assert` survives until the catch block finishes?

Comment: The `throw` [expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) performs a copy of its argument so you aren't throwing the temporary.

Comment: @user657267 That's an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From N4296 (first draft after final C++14) [15.1p3]:

> Throwing an exception copy-initializes (8.5, 12.8) a temporary object,
>   called the exception object. The  temporary is an lvalue and is used
>   to initialize the variable declared in the matching handler (15.3).

So you can't assume that your temporary "survives the throw". If throwing, the copy constructor of an exception object of type `std::exception` will be called with `e` as the argument. The temporary that `e` is bound to will be destroyed when control leaves the full expression containing the call to `my_assert` (either after a normal return or as part of stack unwinding, since you're conditionally throwing the exception).

There are circumstances when the copy construction of the exception object can be elided, but this is not one of them, according to [12.8p31.2]:

> — in a throw-expression (5.17), when the operand is the name of a
>   non-volatile automatic object (*other than a function or catch-clause
>   parameter*) whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost
>   enclosing try-block (if there is one), the copy/move operation from
>   the operand to the exception object (15.1) can be omitted by
>   constructing the automatic object directly into the exception object

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Great answer, precise and sound. Edited the question to sharpen "survives the throw".